# Deployment of optical fiber QGIS Python

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

The subject that I’m working on is the deployment of optical fiber .
I have a shapefile which represents a country containing homes.
And I have another shapefile representing an infrastructure plan of an operator containing boxes (fiber optical room).
[image]
[image]
I want to cut this country into many areas respecting these rules:

- Every area must contain a maximum of 648 houses.
- All houses belonging to an area must be accessible from the boxes through the cable ducts of the infrastructure plan.
- We can attach a house not touching the optical fiber line with a house that touches it

The result must be something like that.
[image]

I have succeed to achieve the first rule. I get this result.
But I couldn't realize tne second one.
[image]

Comment: I don't really understand this rule: 'All houses belonging to an area must be accessible from the boxes through the cable ducts' 
Some of the houses in your proposed solution are clearly not touching your optical fibre line.

Comment: There is another rule :
We can attach a house not touching the optical fiber line with a house that touch.

Comment: is your fibre network FTTP, FTTC or FTTB?

Comment: @Mapperz it's FTTH( Fiber to the home)

Comment: we call it FTTP (Fibre to the Premise) but each route does not take the shortest distance to the house or from the same hubsite.

Comment: Yes, but each house must have access to a fiber optical cable from the infrastructure plan.